# How do I validate PowerShell script syntax in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a C# method that generates powershell scripts.

Is there a way to automatically validate the syntax of the generated scripts directly in C# before running them on the end client?

Comment: Why is this closed? Please vote to reopen, it's a valid question, on topic and in scope. One way would be to unit test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ***possibly*** use the
[`Parser.ParseFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_Language_Parser_ParseFile_System_String_System_Management_Automation_Language_Token____System_Management_Automation_Language_ParseError____) method from the *PowerShell SDK*, which ***might be*** found in the [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) nuget

<sub>***Note** : I have never used this and is totally untested, and truthfully i have no idea whether this will work for you.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and leave feedback.